# Disable AJAX on Chrome for debugging

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, developer-tools

I am debugging an application that has several Ajax calls on setIntervals on different pages. I am having a hard time debugging because since the pages keep refreshing every 5 seconds I don't have enough time to inspect the DOM. If I find the class or ID used to make the AJAX i can delete it on the browser inspector and stop the AJAX. However, this is a large application and I don't know every single class or ID used to make the AJAX call on every page. It is really time-consuming to look for them. All that said, is there a native tool on the browser that allows to disable AJAX? As suggested on another post, I ran this function on the console to override the AJAX but it didn't work:

```
 XMLHttpRequest.prototype.call = function () {};
```

Thank you.